# How can I start animating an UILabel from a particular location in iPad?

Tags: objective-c, animation, core-animation, uilabel, ipad

I need to start animating a UILabel when a button is pressed... the animation should start from the position of the button.
How can I achieve this?

i.e moving label from one end of the screen to another end.

Answer (score 6):

This is acheviced with UIView's animateWithDuration methods, which can be found in the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW111).

A very simple example which should be called when your button is pressed:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
     // set new position of label which it will animate to
     myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
}];
```

Comment: I gave you another upvote since this guy never came back. And of course since your answer helped me. There's just no justice. Then again, he seems to have dropped programming altogether since he never came back to the site, period. Lol, nobody keeps programming and leaves SO.